# Inertia.js alternative of history.push from React.js

Tags: reactjs, inertiajs

I know that in React.js if you want to click on a button that will trigger the changing of the location i can use this:

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

I'm looking for an alternative in Inertia.Js  `https://inertiajs.com/links`, but unfortunately i found just this ex:

```js
<InertiaLink href="/logout" method="post" as="button" type="button">Logout</InertiaLink>
```

Question: How to make an alternative like in react js (`history.push("/home");`)?

Comment: look https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits#browser-history

Comment: @NishargShah, could you please post your comment as answer to be able to accept your answer.

Comment: glad you like my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look out the below docs link

https://inertiajs.com/manual-visits#browser-history